# Stop Forms daily digest messages in Teams channel

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-forms

Someone other than me created a form and somehow got it to post a daily message in our common Teams channel, repeating over and over how many responses the form got so far. Now it's just noise, and no one can remember how they started it, nor how to make it stop.

How do I make it stop?

I've looked in the Edit/Results/Fill tabs at the top and there are no options there related to notifications. I'm not sure where else to look.

[image: Forms noise in Teams]

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It's a "Connector". A Forms connector can apparently do only one thing, namely post "a daily update of responses to your selected form". This is how to remove it:

In the Teams channel's falafel menu, choose Connectors.

[image: go to connectors]

This brings you to a dialog where (possibly after logging in) you can choose to manage configured connectors.

[image: manage configured connectors]

In the next screen, you can remove the connector.